# React Redux Unsubscribe store data binding

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new to React and redux and have an important query.

I want to render an  element to a svg as a child.

For the x,y attributes, I need to take the value from the store data, which is constantly updated on mousemove or click of the svg.

The problem is, as I am binding the attributes inside the component to store state data, whenever the state changes, the rect position gets updated.

Whereas I need to get the x,y only when I am adding to dom and once the component is rendered, I want the attribute values to be unsubscribed.

Any thoughts on how to handle this

Below is the sample code -

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import store from "../Redux/store";

export class Rectangle extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <g>
        <rect
          className="rect1"
          width="100"
          height="50"
          x={store.getState().point_x}
          y={store.getState().point_y}
          ref="rect1"
        ></rect>
      </g>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null)(Rectangle);
```

Comment: show code please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: added code sample in edit, please check